# How do I add values from both of result in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql, relational-database

This is Two result I get from the following two Queries.

**Query one**

```
db.game.aggregate( [ 
{ $group : { _id : "$HomeTeam", shots: { $sum : "$HS" } } },
{ $sort : { shots : -1 } }
])
```

**Query one result**

```
{ "_id" : "Man City", "shots" : 386 }
{ "_id" : "Liverpool", "shots" : 335 }
{ "_id" : "Chelsea", "shots" : 325 }
{ "_id" : "Tottenham", "shots" : 308 }
{ "_id" : "Leicester", "shots" : 298 }
{ "_id" : "Crystal Palace", "shots" : 294 }
{ "_id" : "Man United", "shots" : 284 }
{ "_id" : "Everton", "shots" : 279 }
{ "_id" : "Fulham", "shots" : 274 }
{ "_id" : "Wolves", "shots" : 267 }
{ "_id" : "Newcastle", "shots" : 266 }
{ "_id" : "Southampton", "shots" : 258 }
{ "_id" : "Arsenal", "shots" : 256 }
{ "_id" : "West Ham", "shots" : 245 }
{ "_id" : "Cardiff", "shots" : 230 }
{ "_id" : "Bournemouth", "shots" : 229 }
{ "_id" : "Watford", "shots" : 224 }
{ "_id" : "Burnley", "shots" : 210 }
{ "_id" : "Huddersfield", "shots" : 203 }
{ "_id" : "Brighton", "shots" : 200 }
```

**Query two**

```
db.game.aggregate( [ 
{ $group : { _id : "$AwayTeam", shots: { $sum : "$AS" } } },
{ $sort : { shots : -1 } }
])
```

**Query two result**

```
{ "_id" : "Man City", "shots" : 297 }
{ "_id" : "Chelsea", "shots" : 281 }
{ "_id" : "Man United", "shots" : 242 }
{ "_id" : "Liverpool", "shots" : 239 }
{ "_id" : "Tottenham", "shots" : 228 }
{ "_id" : "Southampton", "shots" : 222 }
{ "_id" : "Bournemouth", "shots" : 218 }
{ "_id" : "Leicester", "shots" : 217 }
{ "_id" : "Everton", "shots" : 216 }
{ "_id" : "Watford", "shots" : 210 }
{ "_id" : "Arsenal", "shots" : 210 }
{ "_id" : "Wolves", "shots" : 207 }
{ "_id" : "Huddersfield", "shots" : 197 }
{ "_id" : "Crystal Palace", "shots" : 197 }
{ "_id" : "West Ham", "shots" : 196 }
{ "_id" : "Cardiff", "shots" : 187 }
{ "_id" : "Fulham", "shots" : 179 }
{ "_id" : "Newcastle", "shots" : 178 }
{ "_id" : "Brighton", "shots" : 165 }
{ "_id" : "Burnley", "shots" : 149 }
```

So how do I make a Query where both the shots are added up. Something like this where the same teams shots are added up.

```
{ "_id" : "Man City", "Totalshots" : 683 }
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

- `$facet` to separate result for both fields `HS` and `AS`
- `$project` to concat both arrays in a single array using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `result` array
- `$group` by `_id` and sum `shots`
- `$sort` by `shots` in descending order

```
db.game.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      HS: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$HomeTeam",
            shots: { $sum: "$HS" }
          }
        }
      ],
      AS: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$AwayTeam",
            shots: { $sum: "$AS" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: { result: { $concatArrays: ["$AS", "$HS"] } } },
  { $unwind: "$result" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$result._id",
      Totalshots: { $sum: "$result.shots" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { Totalshots: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QMogjlXtuFl)